# How to get data from a specific class/member location in the main program from a loaded DLL/Shared Library? [Windows/Linux]

Tags: c++, linux, windows, function-pointers

I am trying to call a function which is located in the program from a DLL.

The program is closed source but the structures are know.

I need to call a function called "GetPlayerPosition" which looks like this:

```
// native GetPlayerPos(playerid, &Float:x, &Float:y, &Float:z)
static cell AMX_NATIVE_CALL n_GetPlayerPos(AMX *amx, cell *params)
{
    CHECK_PARAMS(4);

    CPlayer* pPlayer = pNetGame->GetPlayerPool()->GetAt((BYTE)params[1]);

    if (pPlayer)
    {
        cell* cptr;
        amx_GetAddr(amx, params[2], &cptr);
        *cptr = amx_ftoc(pPlayer->m_vecPos.X);
        amx_GetAddr(amx, params[3], &cptr);
        *cptr = amx_ftoc(pPlayer->m_vecPos.Y);
        amx_GetAddr(amx, params[4], &cptr);
        *cptr = amx_ftoc(pPlayer->m_vecPos.Z);

        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I want to call this part from my DLL/SO:

`pNetGame->GetPlayerPool()->GetAt((BYTE)<my own input data here>);`

I know the streucture/classes are this:

```
typedef struct _VECTOR {
    float X,Y,Z;
} VECTOR, *PVECTOR;

CNetGame    *pNetGame   = NULL;

class CNetGame
{
private:
    CPlayerPool                 *m_pPlayerPool;
public:
    CNetGame();
    ~CNetGame();
    CPlayerPool * GetPlayerPool() { return m_pPlayerPool; };
};

void CNetGame::Init(BOOL bFirst = false)
{
    // Setup player pool
    if(!m_pPlayerPool) {
        m_pPlayerPool = new CPlayerPool();
    } else {
        m_pPlayerPool->ResetPlayerScoresAndMoney();
    }
}

class CPlayerPool
{
private:

    BOOL    m_bPlayerSlotState[MAX_PLAYERS];
    CPlayer *m_pPlayers[MAX_PLAYERS];

public:

    CPlayerPool();
    ~CPlayerPool();

    BOOL New(BYTE bytePlayerID, PCHAR szPlayerName);
    BOOL Delete(BYTE bytePlayerID, BYTE byteReason);

    // Retrieve a player
    CPlayer* GetAt(BYTE bytePlayerID) {
        if (bytePlayerID >= MAX_PLAYERS) { return NULL; }
        return m_pPlayers[bytePlayerID];
    };
};

class CPlayer
{
private:
    BYTE                    m_bytePlayerID;

public:

    CPlayer();
    ~CPlayer() {};

    VECTOR  m_vecPos;

};
```

So how would I call `pNetGame->GetPlayerPool()->GetAt((BYTE)<my own input data here>);` with this setup?

Comment: Normally you call a function in a DLL from a EXE.  I guess you're going to have to find the address of the function and call it like taht

Comment: how could I programatically determine the adress (not IDA/Cheat Engine) - so if a new version comes out, It won't "just" break.

Comment: `GetProcAddress` or variants, I'm guessing

Comment: I don't think that `pNetGame` is an `EXPORT`

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve doing this?

Comment: I need to get the position of a player from a DLL, not a Script (scripts cn call functions, but DLL's cannot, they "can only" *extend* scripting functionality), there are some workaround but the current ones are crashyyy

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20765/discussion-between-tony-the-lion-and-gam-erix)

Comment: Why does this question have a `linux` tag?

Comment: because it has to work on linux too, I can separate code with defines... or separate builds for each system